# Creating a Directory on a remote machine using VB.NET

Tags: .net, web-services

How can I create a directory on a remote server using .NET? Both servers are running Windows Server 2003. I have looked at the system.IO.directory class, and FtpWebRequest, both of which don't seem to do what I need.

If there isn't an existing method for this, I should be able to form a VPN tunnel, map the drive, and use directory.copy, right?

**Update:**
Decided to take Rockinthesixstring's advice and create a web service on the server in which I need to create the directories. I built the following ASMX file, compiled it in visual studio, and was able to successfully invoke it from the browser page that is "automagically" generated from the ASMX file

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel

    <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
    <System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://ttanet.com/")> _
    <System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
    <ToolboxItem(False)> _
    Public Class Service1
        Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
        <WebMethod()> _

        'Here is where we invoke our exposed method'
        Public Sub makeDir(ByVal dirName As String)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/TransferTest/" & dirName)
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Excellent suggestion -Thanks Rockin...

The second half of my question is the best way to invoke it. I need to call it from a VB.NET app. I am trying to invoke it from a browser, like:

```
http://localhost:60870/MakeDirectory.asmx/makeDir?dirName=testingFromURL
```

But it yields:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/makeDir'.
```

I was planning on looping through and sending WebRequestFactory.Create(urlForGetRequest) through an iteration. Is something wrong with the way my URL is structured, Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you have access to the server via a file share?

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: No access via file share. I replaced the local test directory with the IP address, (10.10.10.10/NewDirectory, but it just failed. I thought it failed because I needed to have the drive mapped.

Comment: can you build a web service as I stated below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a [web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx) on the machine that is to have the directory created. Then call the web service from the machine that is doing the creating.  The web service can use the `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory` method.

An alternative method would be to create the directory directly using a UNC Path. (requires a folder share across the network)

Comment: I'm investigating this now. Actually, I think it will work. I'll let you know how it turns out..

Comment: Cool, let us know how it goes.